# Clang: how to force crash/exception of runtime error due to -fsanitize=undefined

Tags: c, clang, undefined-behavior

I just watched an interesting talk on UB (*Undefined Behavior*) and I tried out some things.

Consider the following code:

```objectivec
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x) {
    return x + 10;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    i = INT_MAX - 3;

    printf("i = %d\n",i);
    printf("f(%d) = %d\n",i,f(i));

    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling using:

```bash
clang -O0 -fsanitize=undefined a.c
```

And then running the program, there will occur a runtime error and clang will explain in detail what's wrong:

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483644 + 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

However, the program will continue past the *offending* line and execute the `Hello World` message, **and** the exit status / return code will be 0, as if nothing bad has happened.

How do I force a **hard crash / exception** (like an `assert()` error) in my C program when that happens using clang?

Thanks for any helpful answers in advance.

> PS: I learned that the error message cannot be produced in compile time, only during runtime, but I didn't expect that the consequences were so *loose* when enabling `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Expectations:

```bash
clang -O0 -fsanitize=undefined a.c -o a.out
./a.out
echo $?
```

- `Hello World` does not appear
- exit status is != 0

Comment: Check https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html Specifically *-fno-sanitize-recover=...: print a verbose error report and exit the program;*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html

> For most checks (checks), the instrumented program prints a verbose
> error report and continues execution upon a failed check. You can use
> the following options to change the error reporting behavior:
>
> - `-fno-sanitize-recover=...`: print a verbose error report and exit the program;
> - `-fsanitize-trap=...`: execute a trap instruction (doesn’t require UBSan run-time support). If the signal is not caught, the program will
>   typically terminate due to a SIGILL or SIGTRAP signal.

It sounds like you want to use `-fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined flag.

Full command might look like:
clang -O0 -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined -fsanitize=undefined test.c

Source: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html